# Pointer to protocol passed in as parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c, function, protocols

Is it possible to pass a protocol as a parameter to a function?

```
@protocol A
@end

...
// in other class
- (void)callProto: (Protocol *)protocol
{
   NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromProtocol(protocol));
}
```

There aren't any syntax error in this case. But how can I pass a protocol to this function?

I tried

```
[instance callProto: A];
```

it doesn't work.

Comment: In order to help you out, I think we need a little more info on what you are hoping to achieve by passing a protocol as a function parameter. I don't think callProto: would act like you think.

Comment: Why do you want to pass a protocol as a parameter? What do you need to do with `protocol` inside your `callProto:` method?

Comment: also, the code you posted works fine on my end, just not sure that its going to do what you are expecting it to do.

Comment: Protocol itself normally doesn't contain an implementation of methods defined in a protocol. Are you looking for ways to send messages to objc objects dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare a protocol like this:

`Protocol *p = @protocol(MyProtocolName);`

Then pass it to your function like this:

`[self callProto:p];`

I can't think of why you would need this though.

Comment: You could create dynamic protocols with objc runtime if you want :)

Comment: like I said, I cannot think of why you would need that. It seems to break the reason that protocols exists. I would love to hear a more detailed explanation.